# Cannot fetch Boolean values from database with hibernate createSQLQuery

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, google-app-engine

While fetching Boolean data from database with hibernate SQL query gives the following error trace.In local machine it is working fine.But when deploying it into GAE got the errors.

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of com.fetchinglife.domain.data.dto.EmployeeDTO.extraTask
```

In my EmployeeDTO.java

```
private boolean extraTask;

//getters and setters

public boolean getExtraTask() 
    {
        return extraTask;
    }
public void setExtraTask(boolean extraTask) 
    {
        this.extraTask = extraTask;
    }
```

hibernate createSQLQuery is like,

```
Query query  = session.createSQLQuery("select e.firstName, e.extraTask from Employee as e where e.id= :userId").setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(EmployeeDTO.class));
query.setParameter("userId", userId);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that since you use SQL rather than HQL, Hibernate can't use its mapping information and its database dialect to transform what you have in database into a boolean. Why don't you use HQL for such a query? The HQL is identical to the SQL query :

```
session.createQuery("select e.firstName, e.extraTask from Employee as e where e.id= :userId")
```

Comment: Join two tables are also same how we use it with hibernate createSQLQuery ?

Comment: HQL is perfectly able to make joins between entities. Read http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql